# Flutter, why use "static" in the fromJson method?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
static TodoEntity fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return TodoEntity(
      json['task'] as String,
      json['id'] as String,
      json['note'] as String,
      json['complete'] as bool,
    );
  }

static TodoEntity fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    return TodoEntity(
      snap.data()['task'],
      snap.id,
      snap.data()['note'],
      snap.data()['complete'],
    );
  }
```

I`m studying "fromJson" method right now and

In this example, why they use "static"?

I wonder why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `fromJson` is related the `class` and not the `object` (this is the case for every static variable/method)

So from the name `fromJson`, You need to create `TodoEntity` object from your json, which means you don't have the object yet which means you can't call `fromJson`, So using `static` here is a must,

Another alternative is passing your json via `constructor`, but using `static` is must clean and common.

Example without static:
To create new object from json

```
var json = {...};
TodoEntity todo = TodoEntity();
TodoEntity todo2 = todo.fromJson(json);

or

var json = {...};
TodoEntity todo = TodoEntity();
todo = todo.fromJson(json);
```

as you can see you need always an object (todo) to call `fromJson`

but using static

```
var json = {...};
TodoEntity todo = TodoEntity.fromJson(json);
```

`static` means you can call this function without having an object

Comment: Thanks Gold Ranker ikerfah. but I`m stupid so I still do not understand completely Could you provide the little code please??

Comment: Thanks, but why not just create an object and use other member functions? (I mean just normal functions without fromJson function)

Comment: It totally depend on your use case, you can always use member functions, but as I show you it is not good for this case

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword required to implement "Static Factory Method" pattern for methods which are producing new instances of given class.

If these methods were not `static`, you had to have the an instance of `TodoEntity` to call them.

But they are `static`, so there's no need to create any instance to call them:

```dart
TodoEntity.fromJson(jsonMap);
```

Comment: Thanks, but why not just create an object and use a function?

Comment: This function is meant to be used for creation of new objects. So, if it's not `static` when you'd need to "create an object to create an object". So you'd just end up with two objects instead of one, and first would be completely useless. With `static` function you will get only one object. Try to google more about what is `static` and how it can be used and I hope this would help to understand the subject.